# Bootstrap cards do not wrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm learning django and do not know much about css. I created the following page which is a bunch of products using bootstrap cards.
[image]

as far as I know the following code must have done the wrapping job for these cards, but it does not.

```js
function createProductCards(products) {
    const container = document.querySelector('.card-deck');
  
    products.forEach(product => {
      const cardDiv = document.createElement('div');
      cardDiv.classList.add('card');
  
      const imageTag = document.createElement('img');
      imageTag.setAttribute('src', product.image);
      imageTag.setAttribute('alt', product.name);
      imageTag.classList.add('card-img-top');
      cardDiv.appendChild(imageTag);
      
      const bodyTag = document.createElement('div');
      bodyTag.classList.add('card-body');
      cardDiv.appendChild(bodyTag);
      
      const nameTag = document.createElement('h3');
      nameTag.textContent = product.name;
      nameTag.classList.add('card-title');
      bodyTag.appendChild(nameTag);
      
      
      const descriptionTag = document.createElement('p');
      descriptionTag.textContent = product.description;
      descriptionTag.classList.add('card-text');
      bodyTag.appendChild(descriptionTag);
      
      const genderTag = document.createElement('h6');
      genderTag.textContent = product.gender;
      genderTag.classList.add('card-text');
      bodyTag.appendChild(genderTag);
  
      container.appendChild(cardDiv);
    });
  }
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
main {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}
footer {
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
    padding: 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
    
.card-container {
    justify-content: space-between;
    gap: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

.card-deck {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.card {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    width: 25%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .card-deck {
        flex: 1 0 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
    /* Custom CSS for the two vertical sections */
    
    /* .filter-box-section {
        flex: 1 1 25%;
    padding: 20px;
    } */
    
    /* Adjustments for responsiveness */
    /* @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .card-deck-section .card-deck,
        .filter-box-section {
            flex: 1 1 100%;
        }
    } */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <!-- header part -->

    <main>
        <div class="card-container">
            <div class="card-deck">
                <!-- Your product cards will be dynamically added here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

    <!-- footer part -->

    <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", async function() {
            fetchAllProductsURL = "{% url 'product:all-products' %}"
            response = await sendDataToBackend2(fetchAllProductsURL, null, "GET");
            createProductCards(Object.values(response));
          });
    </script>
    <script src="home.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have another JavaScript snippet that fetch the products from backend. JavaScript here creates cards on screen.
Please let me know if you have any idea why these cards do not wrap in multiple lines? What is the right way to have 4 or 5 cards in each line?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't show any bootstrap cards at all, so it's hard to guess where you're going wrong at. It looks like you are trying to write a custom flex container instead of using the built in bootstrap grid.  Since you are using bootstrap you should just use theirs, but for future reference on non-bootstrap project you can add the `flex-wrap:wrap;` property to whatever element has `display:flex`. But again, don't do that here, just use bootstrap's grid since you already have bootstrap here.

Anything in a bootstrap grid absolutely will wrap columns by default, I suspect you aren't using this. Read up on the docs and see examples here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/grid/

Bootstrap cards also have various layouts to choose from as well: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/card/#card-layout

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row">

  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="card mb-3">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Example Card</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="card mb-3">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Example Card</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="card mb-3">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Example Card</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="card mb-3">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Example Card</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="card mb-3">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Example Card</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

---

EDIT: I see this question is tagged with `bootstrap-4`.  Basically for this stuff there is no real change.  Here are the links to those same pages in the Bootstrap 4 docs:

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/
- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/card/#card-layout

Comment: I added cards in js file after document.createElement. I solved the problem using grid as you said. Thanks